# Двухсторонняя очередь с помощью массива

Tags: java, очередь

Хочу сделать реализацию двухсторонней очередь на основе массива:

```
public class DequeTest<Item> {
    private int N = 0;
    public int size = 1;
    private Item [] s;

    public DequeTest() {
        s = (Item[]) new Object[size];
    }

    public void resize(int k) {
        Item[] copy = (Item[]) new Object[k];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            copy[i] = s[i];
        }
        s = copy;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return N == 0;
    }

    public void addLast(Item item) {
        if (N == s.length)
            resize(2 * s.length);
        s[N++] = item;
    }

    public void addFirst(Item item) {
        Item[] helpArray = (Item[]) new Object[s.length+1];
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            helpArray[j] = s[i];
            j++;
        }
        s = helpArray;
        s[0] = item; // Ошибка
    }

    public void size() {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("i: " + i + " "  + s[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DequeTest test = new DequeTest();
        Object obj1 = new Object();
        Object obj2 = new Object();
        Object obj3 = new Object();
        Object obj4 = new Object();
        Object obj5 = new Object();
        Object obj6 = new Object();
        test.addLast(obj1);
        test.addLast(obj2);
        test.addLast(obj3);
        test.addLast(obj4);
        test.addLast(obj5);
        test.addFirst(obj6);
        test.size();
    }
}
```

В методе `addFirst` я копирую значения из оригинального массива `s` в массив `helpArray` и таким образом произвожу сдвиг массива на единицу, освобождая нулевое значение (`s[0]`). В этом же методе я хочу поместить в `s[0]` значение входящей переменной `item`. Но происходит ошибка, и вместо этого значение помещается в конец, а сам массив "оттягивается" назад. Если же написать `s[8] = item`, то значение займет 8ю ячейку, а массив останется на месте.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Используйте коллекции

Comment: Не знаю какая у вас ошибка выходит, но я запустил ваш же код и у меня все отработало так, как должно(судя по вашему описанию)

Comment: Интересно как, ну да ладно. Если убрать каст, то вылетает type parameter cannot initialized directly. Я не знаю как инициализировать дженерик. А насчет кода, я могу только исправить метод addFirst, чтобы массив сдвигался ближе к середине и не приходилось двигать все элементы при вставке первого элемента. Что еще можно подправить.

Comment: @KojerDefor Есть ли вообще смысл пилить свой костыль, когда java уже предлагает реализации всех основных структур, и Deque в их числе(реализуется в LinkedList). Для такой задачи самым оптимальным вариантом является использовать двусвязный список - в нем добавление и удаление элементов выполняется за O(1) времени

Comment: если делать двустороннюю очередь на массиве, то лучше завести переменные с индексами начала и конца данных в массиве. Тогда для добавление элемента в начало очереди будет достаточно уменьшить индекс начального элемента (обработав случай, когда он становится меньше нуля) и записав в ячейку с этим индексом новый элемент. Таким образом перенос элементов потребуется только когда количество элементов превысит размер массива. Так работает стандартный `ArrayDeque`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблемы в коде:

1. **Ошибка**. В `addFirst` не происходит увеличение значения `N`. Это может приводить к перезаписи элементов вместо добавления в конец в методе `addLast`.
2. Переменная `size` используется всего один раз, да при этом ещё и является `public`.
3. При каждом вызове `addFirst` происходит пересоздание массива, хотя это следует делать только если массив уже заполнен, да и увеличивать длину массива не на 1, а, например, в 2 раза, по аналогии с `addLast`.
4. Действительно ли метод `resize` должен быть публичным?
5. Копирование массива вручную в методах `resize` и `addFirst`.
6. Методу `size` больше подойдёт название `print`.

В итоге получается так:

```
public class DequeTest<Item>
{
    private static final int
            DEFAULT_SIZE = 1,
            GROW_COEF = 2;

    private Object[] array;
    private int elementsCount = 0;

    public DequeTest()
    {
        array = new Object[DEFAULT_SIZE];
    }

    public void addFirst(Item item)
    {
        ensureCapacity();
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, array, 1, elementsCount);
        array[0] = item;
        elementsCount++;
    }

    public void addLast(Item item)
    {
        ensureCapacity();
        array[elementsCount++] = item;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return elementsCount == 0;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("i: " + i + " " + array[i]);
        }
    }

    private void ensureCapacity()
    {
        if (elementsCount + 1 > array.length)
        {
            array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length * GROW_COEF);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: я бы вообще убрал приведение массива, слишком верный способ прострелить ногу

Comment: @etki по идее ведь, покуда массив используется только внутри класса и с осознанием того, что он на самом деле `Object[]`, проблем быть не должно. Действительно ли будет "спокойнее" хранить как `private Object[] array;` и кастовать к `Item` в get-методах?

Comment: как правило, все истории с простреленной ногой начинаются именно так. Лучше просто не вешать на стену ружье и если он является Object[], то и пользоваться им как Object[]. Да, касты и теоретическая возможность положить туда не то останутся.

Comment: А зачем вообще использовать тип `Object` если класс параметризован?

Comment: @I.Perevoz так вот в представленном коде всё нормально работает и с `Object[] array`. А вот get-методы нужно будет писать так: `return (Item)array[index];`.

Comment: @Regent я и не спорю про нормальную работу. Просто практического смысла в `Object[]` не вижу.

Comment: @I.Perevoz по факту ведь всё равно будет `Object[]`, даже если назвать его `Item[]`. Как можно "прострелить себе ногу", используя `Item[] array`, сказать не могу, однако наверняка у etki были основания так говорить. Плюс и лично мне запись `(Item[])new Object[]` не нравится по каким-то внутренним ощущениям.

Comment: @Regent, посмотрел вопросы по инстанцированию массивов параметризованным типом и "под капот" ArrayDeque. И действительно - это самый оптимальный способ.

Comment: @I.Perevoz да и в том же `ArrayList` используется `Object[] elementData`. Ещё есть какие-то уточнения в рамках этого вопроса?

Comment: @Regent, Спасибо за помощь, но метод 'addFirst' по прежнему добавляет элементы в конец массива. На счет каста, я брал инфу с видео, где лектор объясняет, что по другому никак. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLmyZetBKFw&index=16&list=PLxc4gS-_A5VDXUIOPkJkwQKYiT2T1t0I8

Comment: @KojerDefor я не вижу проблем в коде в ответе. Вот [пример онлайн](https://goo.gl/85YStc) с тем, что код работает. Если на каких-то данных код работает неправильно - приведите ссылку на этот пример в https://www.tutorialspoint.com.

Comment: Действительно, извините за лишнее беспокойство.